# DolphinDB JIT doesn't support break and continue in while-loop and for-loop?

Tags: jit, dolphindb

Recently I found that DolphinDB has supported JIT from version [1.01](https://github.com/dolphindb/release/tree/master/1.01). But I found that `break` and `continue` doesn't work in for-loop or while-loop. I tried something like this:

```
@jit
def foo() {
   for(i in 1..10) {
     break
   }
}
foo()
```

```
@jit
def foo() {
    i = 0
    while(i < 100) {
       continue
    }
}
foo()
```

both of them doesn't work, and throw exceptions. Since `break` and `continue` are pretty common 
in my previous scripts, it's very  inconvenience if they are not supported. So my question is are there any problem with my code, or will them be supported in later releases?

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout version 1.01.2. This version supported the use of `break` and `continue` in JIT